# php-language-api and html text problem

Tags: php, google-language-api

i want to use this [php-language-api](http://code.google.com/p/php-language-api/source/browse/trunk/)
i think it is great but with text only
it can not wrok with html text
see

```
$text = htmlspecialchars('<a href="test.php">test.php</a>');
$str = Google_Translate_API::translate($text, 'en', 'ar');
```

or

```
$text = '<a href="test.php">test.php</a>';
$str = Google_Translate_API::translate($text, 'en', 'ar');
```

in the two cases its not work good

Comment: will the text always be anchor tags or could it be larger HTML snippets?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
$text = '<a href="test.php">test.php</a>';
$str = Google_Translate_API::translate(strip_tags($text), 'en', 'ar');
```

Comment: right okay, think a downvote is harsh though since you didnt specify that